# Time complexity for finding whether a given number is a power of 2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to calculate the time complexity for a function return below-

```
int isPowerof2(unsigned int num)
{
     if(((~num)&1) == 1)
          return 1;
      return 0;
}
```

I think it should be O(1) but i am not sure the complexity for negation. Can somebody please help me in understanding how to identify the complexity for this. Thanks!

Edit- What if in case of a single number consider it as an n inputs and the functions checks for power of 2 , what would be the complexity in that case

Comment: The size of the input is fixed (it is a single unsigned int).  Talking about algorithmic complexity doesn't even make sense in that case.

Comment: Yes, a single i/p. So was I got confused when asked abt this. As well consider if I have n inputs then what would be the complexity

Comment: I think it would make more sense to ask "What if the type of the input could have any number of bits?  How would the time complexity grow as a function of the number of bits?"  Of course, then you wouldn't be using the standard & operator - you would have to define a new bitwise AND that worked for an arbitrary number of bits.

Comment: @mbeckish: What do you mean by arbitrary number of bits? Are you suggesting bits > 31 ?

Comment: Yes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: @mbeckish: As well for the given algorithm what would be the time complexity(even though it does not make any sense in it)? I had said as constant and was told wrong.

Comment: That algorithm doesn't look right to me.  An integer is a power of 2 iff it has exactly 1 non-zero bit.

Comment: @unix_user the time complexity of any algorithm is always based on the model of computation assumed. It is relatively common to accept a powerful model where bitwise operations with a number of fixed size bit length runs in constant time, but depending to whom you are talking they can just assume a different computational model which doesn't have such operation and thus it might no longer take only constant time.

Comment: the algorithm is incorrect it should be [`return v && !(v & (v - 1));`](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2). @mbeckish: It *does* make sense to talk about time complexity even for a "single" input e.g., [log2 of an integer could be computed  using `O(N)`, `O(log N)` algorithms](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) where N is proportional to number of bits in the integer.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Yes, if the number of bits is variable - see my further comments about arbitrary precision math.  In the original post, the number of bits is also constant.

Comment: @mbeckish It makes sense to talk about algorithmic complexity. Perhaps the answer is too trivial for you to think it doesn't. It *could* be that `~num` were not a constant time operation but the time it takes is proportional to `num`. This is not the case, but even since it doesn't, the function has an algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @phant0m - It's not that it is too trivial.  Algorithmic complexity is a computer science concept that I don't think applies when the size of the input is constant.  You can certainly try to ascertain how many clock cycles the function would take to run for different inputs, but not using O(N) notation - what would N be?  Number of bits? No, that's fixed at size_of(unsigned int) for this function.

Comment: @mbeckish It's a matter of perspective. The OP was probably thinking of the value of `num` being `N`. It's only clear that the input is constant if you understand how it works, that's why I thought it might seem to trivial or obvious to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A power of two, represented in binary, has exactly *one* bit set, all others are zero.

Subtracting one will invert all bits right of of and including the rightmost one:

```
110101100 - 1=> 110101011 (in the case of zero, all bits get inverted)
```

> We postulate that **`num & (num - 1)`** will evaluate to zero if and only if `num` is a power of two.

**If `num` is in fact a power of two**, there is a single bit set in total, subtracting one will render that bit zero and set all bits to its right to one.

It follows, that `num` and `num - 1` *cannot* share any set bits. Thus, `num & (num - 1)` evaluates to 0.

**If `num` is *not* a power of two** (and not zero), there are *at least* two bits set. When subtracting one, only the rightmost set bit is changed and those to its right, it follows, that the other ones *will not* be affected.

Thus, `num` and `num - 1` share at most one set bit. We conclude that `num & (num - 1)` cannot evaluate to zero for `num` not zero and not a power of two.

It follows that the correct check is: `num && !(num & (num - 1))`

**Complexity**: On a regular computer, all binary operations happen in constant time. Because there is a fixed amount of constant time operations, the entire function will return in constant time: `O(1)`.

When you perform `n` calls to that function, you do a constant time amount of work each time you call it. When `n` doubles, the amount of work doubles. It follows, that the complexity for that case is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Modern processors do basic arithmetic and logic operations on integers of machine word size in a constant number of clocks independent of the values of those integers. So, all of those operations in the function are O(1) and since there's a fixed number of the operations, the entire function is O(1).

Btw, the function does not tell whether the given number is or is not a power of 2. It tells whether or not it's a multiple of 2 as it only looks at the least significant bit of `num`.

The correct check for a power of 2 would be something like this:

```
int isPowerof2(unsigned int num)
{
  return (num != 0) && ((num & (num - 1) == 0);
}
```